# store sql statement in MySQL then run it

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

Is it possible to store the following SQL statement in MySQL then run it in a prepared statement?

Mysql table:

**Table name**: mystatements

**Columns**:id, statements

The following syntax is stored in the **statements** field:

```
 SELECT id, AES_DECRYPT(secret,'$key') as txtsecret  
 FROM TABLE_1
```

Now in php:

first: I do a select query to get my statement

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT statements FROM mystatements limit 1");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$statement.=$row['txtstatement'];
}
```

second: using the variable (**$statement**) from the the query above and add it to query below to run the in the prepared statement:

```
$key='password123';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($statement);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['txtsecret'];
}
```

Also my stored syntax contains **AES_DECRYPT(secret,'$key')** just to complicate things. is what i'm trying to achieve possible? have I gone about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: Hi, Do you need replace "$key" and "?" from query saved in the database?

Comment: I dont think so, I need $key to execute the statement  as I don't want to write the decrypt key in plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..

```
$key='password123';
$sql = str_replace('$key', $key, $statement); //replace $key to correct value
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
```

Result:

```
SELECT id, AES_DECRYPT(secret,'$key') as txtsecret FROM TABLE_1
```

to

```
SELECT id, AES_DECRYPT(secret,'password123') as txtsecret FROM TABLE_1
```

Comment: Hi Cuchu, as i said in my previous comment i dont want to store my decrypt key in plain text

Comment: In $statement you have a query in string format, only replace $key to the correct value.